# BigQuery Views cannot be edited, only deleted and re-saved

Tags: google-bigquery

This is more of a bug report than a question, but Stack Overflow is the official support channel for BigQuery so I'm not sure where else to post this.

Right now if I have a view in BigQuery, when I try to edit it by clicking on "Details", editing the SQL, then clicking "Save View", I get the "View Saved" popup, but when I query the view again nothing has actually changed. The only way to change the view is to delete it and save a new one with the same name, which is pretty annoying every time I want to edit a view. This seems like a bug. Is it already known? Is there a timeline for it to be fixed? Is there somewhere else I should be reporting this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a UI-specific bug that we began pushing earlier in the week. The issue was exactly as your described: updating an existing view would report success, but not actually change the SQL query.  We pushed a fix to production yesterday and the issue should now be resolved.  You will need to refresh your BigQuery UI to pick up the new version and again be able to update views as expected.

Thanks for the bug report, and sorry for any inconvenience!  Just FYI, another channel for bug reports (which Stack Overflow sometimes isn't a huge fan of) is our [external issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list).